# WPF DataGrid Row Issue

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF datagrid bound to a collection object.

I'm facing a weird behavior that some times some row is pushed to right as a result , the entire row looks shifted to right , not sure when exactly it is happening but can see it many times.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Any luck? I found the same issue on one computer.

Answer (score 1):

It is connected to rendering Row headers. This only happens when

```
HeadersVisibility="Column"
```

is set.

For some ugly workarounds see these discussions:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/af7cd462-febe-482b-9a04-61b076933c7b
- http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/47047

HTH

Edit:

I just tried setting the folowing:

```
HeadersVisibility="All"
RowHeaderWidth="0"
```

and it seems to help to avoid the issue.